# Swap the foreign key in two tables in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, foreign-keys

I have two table in Oracle TABLE_A and TABLE_B both table have around 20000 to 30000 records.

The records in TABLE_B are linked to the records in TABLE_A via a foreign key -
(TABLE_B contains the Primary Key of TABLE_A)

I need to swap the Foreign key. i.e.

I want that now TABLE_A should contain the Primary key of TABLE_B. 
(It is a functional requirement - because of some validations at the front end, the updates on these tables in the current form of database implementation are not possible.)

Also, while doing this, I want that the records that were linked from       (TABLE_B -> TABLE_A) still remain linked. 
Now through the new Foreign key (TABLE_A -> TABLE_B).

The FOREIGN KEY can be moved easily, by a couple of ALTER TABLE commands, the main problem area is keeping the data and re-linking it correctly.

The most obvious way to do this would involve taking backups of the entire tables and then creating new scripts to re-insert the updated data in both table.

Is there any faster way to do this without any chances of error.

Comment: Unless the tables are in a 1:1 relationship -- ie. each row in Table A has one row in table B, and each row in table B has one row in Table A -- I don't see this working. If they are 1:1, I don't understand why they are two tables and not one.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, 1:1 relationships are common in superclass/subclass models. Avoids lots of NULL columns in a single wide table.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp yes I suppose so -- it would be quite the error to start off with the superclass referencing the subclass table though.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to think how the model could have been muddled in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following structure:

```
TABLE_A (a_id [pk], ...)
TABLE_B (b_id [pk], a_id, ...)
  unique constraint on TABLE_B (a_id)
  referential constraint TABLE_B (a_id) -> TABLE_A (a_id)
```

You can do something like this, assuming your system can handle a short outage:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_A ADD (b_id NUMBER);

MERGE INTO TABLE_A t USING
  (SELECT b_id, a_id FROM TABLE_B) s
ON (t.a_id = s.a_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET t.b_id = s.b_id;

ALTER TABLE TABLE_A ADD CONSTRAINT a_b_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES TABLE_B (b_id);

ALTER TABLE TABLE_B DROP COLUMN a_id;
```

For only 30K records this should take very little time.

The only bits missing from the above is dropping the old primary key constraint on TABLE_B and adding the new one on TABLE_A(b_id).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It works fine.Just a small thing that I'd like to point out is that the last step you mentioned, won't be required as we still need b_id to be the primary key of TABLE_B. and for TABLE_A the primary key remains a_id.
Also, the in the syntax of MERGE statement, the USING keyword was missing I have suggested a edit for that in your answer.